# How to convert Time format to today's time in Date format in java?

Tags: java, date, date-format, java-time

I have a value of `"00.00.00"` in Time format and I want to convert it to a value in Date format, such as `"2019-09-02 00.00.00"`.

Comment: Does the date has to be the current date? If yes, create a new `LocalDateTime` and then apply the methods `withHour()`, `withMinute()` and `withSecond()`

Comment: For the vast majority of purposes don’t convert date and/or time from a string in one format to a string in another format. Instead keep date and time in proper date and time objects such as `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime`.  When you receive a string, parse it into an appropriate object first thing. Only when you need to hand out a string (g.e., displaying one to the user), format your date/time object into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH.mm.ss"); 
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.parse(yourString, format));
```

Your result is not default of LocalDateTime so to get your result just use another formatter :

```
 DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
 String result = dt.format(format2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the end result you want is a string then you can format the date to a string and append them

```
String str = "00.00.00";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

 String dateTime = date.format(formatter) + " " + str;
```

or in a more compact format

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
String dateTime = String.format("%s %s", LocalDate.now().format(formatter), str);
```

If on the other hand the time is always "00.00.00" you can include it in your formatter pattern

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 00.00.00");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String dateTime = date.format(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");
String newDateTimeFormatter = ldt.format(dtf);
```

if you try this.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd '00.00.00'");
String newDateTimeFormatter = ldt.format(dtf);
```